# ant sub menu cannot change to vertical

Tags: reactjs, antd

from
[image: from]

to
[image: expected]

I want to ask How to create Menu like this (my image). I have been read documentation on this https://ant.design/components/menu/ about menu when i change mode vertical it's only dropdown change to the right position.

Comment: Which attachment? Also can you show the code you wrote?

Comment: @JayCodist that's image, Code like documentation menu on link.but when i try change to vertical only dropdown.i want to create menu style like that image

Comment: So, you basically want the "envelope" icon to go on top of the "Navigation One" title, instead of beside it?

Comment: @JayCodist yes i want to envelope icon to go on top navigation one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All antd Menu titles respond to custom CSS styling. Simple make either the text or the icon `display: block;` and they will display on different lines. Also note that antd default styling assigns fixed line-height to the menu items, so you'll need to "unset" that rule (`line-height: unset;`) in your CSS to achieve multi-line Menu items.

Here's a codepen to illustrate:
https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/GRoqGyV